# need to set inline style="width: window.innerWidth"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve the following effect:

```
<div id='leftSide' style="width: window.innerWidth"> AS WIDE AS CLIENT WINDOW </div>
```

I don't think it is possible to code it as above.  The reason is, "window.innerWidth" is a **Javascript** attribute of the window object -- and I don't see how to use that value in my inline CSS.

Also, I avoid 'onLoad()' handlers.  I know I can add an onLoad() handler function to handle the page load in the body tag of the page and then use all the javascript I want to set the width.  But I don't like using onload handlers in my pages.

So is there *some* way to access the 'window.innerWidth' value in my inline'd CSS here?

Comment: If the element is a child of an element that spans the full width of the window (e.g. body), you can use `width: 100%`. Does that not work?

Comment: The div in my question here, is an outermost div -- that has two nested divs, a left one and a right one, inline-block style on the two nested divs so they're side-by-side.  I use a % percentage width on the two nested divs and found out the hard way that the containing div *must* have a hard number like "1200px" -- if the containing outermost div has **100%** as its width, the inner divs -- each being width=49% -- are now 49% of 100% (but what is 100% ??  It's nothing, so the 49% width of width = 100% is width=zero for the inner divs.  I need a real number on this outermost div.

Comment: `inline-block style on the two nested divs`. Inline-block elements by default have a space between them, which is perhaps why it's breaking. To test, remove the white space between the nested elements, as that will remove the default gap between them.

Comment: @ralph.m Inline-block elements don't have spaces between them by default. There usually is a space in practice though because the elements in the markup are on different lines, and the newline is interpreted by the browser as a space. This is similar to how newlines in `p` elements show up as spaces in the browser. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yPc2c/

Comment: @ralph.m Oops, my bad. Looks like you already covered what I mentioned in my last comment. The first sentence was somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 5):

Just use 100vw width:

`style="width:100vw"`

`vw` means relative to viewport width. Worried about browser compatibility? Use `100%` instead. But using `vw` is better in case it's in a small container.

Comment: I've never seen "vw" before.  This solved my problem.  Jeez, thanks -- I was hoping there was a simple answer.

Comment: @CFHcoder could you accept the answer (click on the check mark) if the answer answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have You try use something like this ?

```
<script>
document.getElementById("leftSide").style.width=window.innerWidth;
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, the script tags syntax you indicate above -- will not work inside an inline'd **"style=width: "** CSS statement that is used within a div.

Comment: @CFHcoder Yes sorry this was only for inspiration ;) I have edited code what do you think about this ?

Comment: Do you really need jQuery for this?

Comment: @CFHcoder You have already solved ths problem ? I have edited code unnecessarily with - .... anyway look to pure javascript solution in my edited code. Maybe this will help you in future.